# custom search between users in mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

**data**

```
location:{
    type: String ,
    required: true
}
```

---

**HTML register**

```
<label>location*</label>
<select name="location" class="long" id="location">
    <label class="optional">location</label>
    <option value="blah">blah</option>
    <option value="blahh">blahh</option>
    <option value="blahh">blahh</option>
</select>
```

I want the user to see other users profile(as suggestion) that in the same location so i add location select in register form 
So how can I pull his location from his database and put it as a condition in `find({})`

> - Is this possible ?
> - Or is there any better or more practical way to do that ?

Comment: you can store user's location in lat long & retrieve using mongo geo query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if I fully understand your question, but I will answer you according to my understanding of the question. If you want to be able to calculate the distance between users locations, then this is how you would go about doing it.

1. store the location of the user as a field in the users document.

   ```
   {
     id:1,
     name: John,
     coordinates:[latitude, longitude]
   }
   ```
2. On your server you can then use the $geoNear pipeline to get all the users close to the `otherUsersCoordinates` which is also a list [latitude, longitude].

   ```
   db.users.aggregate([
    {
     $geoNear:{
     near: {coordinates: otherUsersCoordinates},
     distanceField: "distance.calculated",
     maxDistance: radius,
     num: parseInt(limit),
     spherical: true
    }
   ]);
   ```

If this is what you were asking the answer is yes the above approach would get you all the nearest users. You can then use the results to populate your HTML as you would like.

Comment: On older mongo servers ( < 3.2) geo queries are slower, you need to update your mongo server if you want results faster.

Comment: True I initially had that problem on a project I was working on and I came across this [link](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/geospatial-performance-improvements-in-mongodb-3-2).

Comment: redis may be can fast the result by cache server